# Android listview annoying black line

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

[image]

The black line is added between my listview and the logo header. Any ideas on what to look for in the mark up? I don't understand where its coming from.

Answer (score 1):

use this function,

```
listview.setCacheColorHint(0);
```

hope it helps...